# protect method I have declared as synchronized but output that it gives seems to be that the method is not synchronized

Tags: java, synchronized

I thought The output would be

```
lol(0) lol(1) lol(2) lol(3) lol(4) lol(5) lol(6) lol(7) lol(8) lol(9) LOL(0) 
LOL(1) LOL(2) LOL(3) LOL(4) LOL(5) LOL(6) LOL(7) LOL(8) LOL(9)
```

because protect method I have synchronized

but the output comes

```
lol(0) LOL(0) lol(1) LOL(1) LOL(2) lol(2) LOL(3) lol(3) lol(4) LOL(4) lol(5) 
LOL(5) LOL(6) lol(6) lol(7) LOL(7) lol(8) LOL(8) LOL(9) lol(9)
```

why is it so?

`ThreadBare` class:

```
class ThreadBare implements Runnable
{ 

    String msg;
    ThreadBare(String m)
    {
        msg=m;
    }

     public  synchronized  void  protect()  //synchronized
    {
        for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
        {
            System.out.print(" "+msg+"("+i+")");
            try
            {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            }
            catch(InterruptedException ie)
            {
                System.out.println(ie);
            }
        }
    }

     public void run()
    {
        protect();
    }
}
```

`MainBare` class:

```
class MainBare
{

    public static void main(String args[ ] )
    {
        Thread t1=new Thread(new ThreadBare("lol"));

        Thread t2=new Thread(new ThreadBare("LOL"));

        t1.start();
        t2.start();

    }
}
```

Comment: as you sleep the thread, the lock is released .

Comment: Why should two different objects bother if they access a synchronized non-static method? Your synchronized `protect()` method is saved against multiple access __on the same object__.

Comment: what is lock I cant get u?

Comment: There are 2 differents `ThreadBare` instances. Both contains a synchronized method, but this doesn't mean the method is synchronized with all instances of the class.

Comment: As Tom said, you have two different objects, and you synchronize the whole method which is equivalent to `synchronize(this) { ... }` for each object `this` is obviously different, so you are actually not synchronizing those two particular objects at all. you need to synchronize on a common object, so that when the first thread acquires the lock the second will have to wait until the first finishes and releases the lock by either leaving the synchronized block or being interrupted.

Comment: thanks A4L & Tom I understood where I went wrong.

Comment: Beware: thread.sleep does not release the monitor/lock as you say in one of previous comments ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can read under https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/syncmeth.html, using the `synchronize` keyword on a method will synchronize the method calls of *that object* only. Since you create two objects, `t1` and `t2`, they are not synchronized against each other.

You could solve this by making a single object with the protected method that is passed as a reference to `t1` and `t2`, with `t1` and `t2` then calling `thatObject.protect()`.

Alternatively, you could refactor `protect()` to be static, in which case, synchronization will be class-wide.

Explanation:

Using the `synchronize` keyword on a method will internally use `this`/the classes instance to synchronize on. Using `synchronize` on a static method will instead use the `Class` instance to synchronize on, making it work across different object instances.

Comment: I did that only & thanks @Torque.